# Regex - get all matches inside a string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
$sContent = "t('Dashboard').' '.t('Settings Test').' '.t('My Test').' '.t('Other test')";
```

What I need is a regular expression that get each separate t('') values like:

```
t('Dashboard')
t('Settings Test')
...
```

In PHP I used:

```
$sRegExp = '/t\((.*)\)/i';
preg_match_all($sRegExp, $sContent, $aResults);
```

I get the same result with main string:

```
t('Dashboard').' '.t('Settings Test').' '.t('My Test').' '.t('Other test')
```

Comment: Please look at [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$sRegExp = '/t\((.*?)\)/
```

or

```
$sRegExp = '/t\(([^\)]*)\)/
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's assume that you never won't use ' inside that text. Then this should help.

```
preg_match_all('/t\(\'(?<=t\(\')([^\']*(?!=\'\)))\'\)/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

Ok, if you want to use ' symbol, you must escape it with \, then try to use the following pattern

```
/t\(\'(?<=t\(\')(((?=\\\\)\\\\\'|[^\'])*(?!=\'\)))\'\)/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function:

```
$sContent = "t('Dashboard').' '.t('Settings Test').' '.t('My Test').' '.t('Other test')";
$sContents = explode(".' '.", $sContent);
```